# jquery smooth scroll on single hash anchor to get on top

Tags: jquery, scroll

I use this jquery smooth scroll function:

```
$('a[href*=#]').on('click',function(event){
//event.preventDefault(); // nope
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},500); 
});
```

It work perfectly when an anchor link is clicked:

```
<a href="#section1">smooth scroll</a>
```

Except when a single hash is clicked to go back on top, like:

```
<a href="#">home</a>
```

In this case i see the top of the page but without the smooth scroll effect..

I know that if the link call the id of the first element on the page everything work,
just wondering if there is a way to use the single hash to smoothly scrool on top

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add an anchor data-anchor-offset="30" at sections and check the anchor.To your case defaultAnchorOffset will be used.Take a working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/v4tzngmr/

```
$('a[href*=#]').on('click',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
    var defaultAnchorOffset = 0;
    var $anchor = $('#' + this.hash.substring(1));
    var anchorOffset = $anchor.data('anchor-offset');

    if (!anchorOffset) // for when anchor doesn't have the offset attribute like Section 4
    anchorOffset = defaultAnchorOffset;
    var offset = $anchor.offset() === undefined ? 0 : $anchor.offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset - anchorOffset
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the a link .gototop and it will work. You will add 0 to scrollTop and it will go to top of page :)

```
$('.gototop').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
});
```

You code doesn't work because if after the hash you don't add the ID of the element it will not get the offset of the element. $(this.hash) is the same as $("#divid") and will select the element with ID divid, and because you are not giving nothing after the # it will not receive an element to search for offset and it is causing an error. If you check your console it will show this :

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined :)*

Answer (score 0):

Answer of Giannis Grivas connected to several other solutions from StackOverflow

Nota bene: I am totall dummy for JQuery. I just connected few solutions and it works!

HTML:

```
<a href="#section1">smooth scroll</a>
<a href="#">home</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {
        $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {                    
                var defaultAnchorOffset = 0;
                var $anchor = $('#' + this.hash.substring(1));
                var anchorOffset = $anchor.data('anchor-offset');

                var href = $.attr(this, 'href');                    

                if (!anchorOffset)
                    anchorOffset = defaultAnchorOffset;
                var offset = $anchor.offset() === undefined ? 0 : $anchor.offset().top;

                $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: offset - anchorOffset
                  }, 500, 
                    function () {
                      window.location.hash = href;
                    }
                  );
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Also useful (for marking anchor of class 'show' active):

`function markActive(adr) {
            adr = $(adr).filter(".show");
            $('.show').not(adr).removeClass('active');  
            $(adr).addClass('active');
        }`

-add function call after variable declaration in previous function. Cheers!